# Can this beautifulsoup script be simplified with Regex?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote some beautifulsoup scripts, and one part seems really redundant, I am thinking if it can be simplified with Regex.

All posts from this forum are marked with different colors, what I did is to search each color with one line. For six colors I did six lines with only one words difference.

```
red = soup.find_all('a', style="font-weight: bold;color: red")
blue = soup.find_all('a', style="font-weight: bold;color: blue")
green = soup.find_all('a', style="font-weight: bold;color: green")
purple = soup.find_all('a', style="font-weight: bold;color: purple")
orange = soup.find_all('a', style="font-weight: bold;color: orange")
lime = soup.find_all('a', style="color: green")
```

I am not sure if it is possible to be simplified. Maybe something like:

```
re.compile("(color: red|blue|green|purple|orange)", re.(whatever the letter is))
```

if it's not regex, or could it be something else?

This is partial DOM:

```
<th class="common">
<label>
<img alt="" src="images/green001/agree.gif"/>
<img alt="本版置顶" src="images/green001/pin_1.gif"/>
                                                             </label>
<em>[<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=230&amp;filter=type&amp;typeid=140">美臀</a>]</em> <span id="thread_10431427"><a href="thread-10431427-1-1.html" style="font-weight: bold;color: blue">(本中)(HND-???) 二宮ひかり</a></span>
<img alt="附件" class="attach" src="images/attachicons/common.gif"/>
</th>
<td class="author">
<cite>
<a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;uid=12737809">第一會所新片</a><img align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/thankyou.gif"/>6                                        </cite>
<em>2019-4-22</em>
</td>
<td class="nums"><strong>2</strong> / <em>12234</em></td>
<td class="nums">5.02G / MP4                
                </td>
<td class="lastpost">
<em><a href="redirect.php?tid=10431427&amp;goto=lastpost#lastpost">2019-4-23 20:22</a></em>
<cite>by <a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;username=zj376104288">zj376104288</a></cite>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody><!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<tbody id="stickthread_10431424">
<tr>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10431424-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_common.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="icon">
                                                                    </td>
<th class="common">
<label>
<img alt="" src="images/green001/agree.gif"/>
<img alt="本版置顶" src="images/green001/pin_1.gif"/>
                                                             </label>
<em>[<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=230&amp;filter=type&amp;typeid=1303">VR</a>]</em> <span id="thread_10431424"><a href="thread-10431424-1-1.html" style="font-weight: bold;color: red">(WAAP)(WPVR-???)葵百合香</a></span>
<img alt="附件" class="attach" src="images/attachicons/common.gif"/>
</th>
<td class="author">
<cite>
<a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;uid=12737809">第一會所新片</a><img align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/thankyou.gif"/>5                                        </cite>
<em>2019-4-22</em>
</td>
<td class="nums"><strong>0</strong> / <em>7265</em></td>
<td class="nums">3.85G / MP4                
                </td>
<td class="lastpost">
<em><a href="redirect.php?tid=10431424&amp;goto=lastpost#lastpost">2019-4-22 20:57</a></em>
<cite>by <a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;username=%B5%DA%D2%BB%95%FE%CB%F9%D0%C2%C6%AC">第一會所新片</a></cite>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody><!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<tbody id="stickthread_10431423">
<tr>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10431423-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_common.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="icon">
                                                                    </td>
<th class="common">
<label>
<img alt="" src="images/green001/agree.gif"/>
<img alt="本版置顶" src="images/green001/pin_1.gif"/>
                                                             </label>
<em>[<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=230&amp;filter=type&amp;typeid=1303">VR</a>]</em> <span id="thread_10431423"><a href="thread-10431423-1-1.html" style="font-weight: bold;color: red">(KMP)(SAVR-???)舞島あかり</a></span>
<img alt="附件" class="attach" src="images/attachicons/common.gif"/>
</th>
<td class="author">
<cite>
<a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;uid=12737809">第一會所新片</a><img align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/thankyou.gif"/>4                                        </cite>
<em>2019-4-22</em>
</td>
<td class="nums"><strong>0</strong> / <em>6226</em></td>
<td class="nums">23.39G / MP4               
                </td>
<td class="lastpost">
<em><a href="redirect.php?tid=10431423&amp;goto=lastpost#lastpost">2019-4-22 20:57</a></em>
<cite>by <a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;username=%B5%DA%D2%BB%95%FE%CB%F9%D0%C2%C6%AC">第一會所新片</a></cite>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody><!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<tbody id="stickthread_10431422">
<tr>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10431422-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_common.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="icon">
                                                                    </td>
```

Comment: which forum? Is there an url?

Comment: it's just some random website in China, hehe~ @QHarr

Comment: Can we use the url to help answer?

Comment: certainly we could, let me go check it out. @QHarr

Comment: hey chief, I checked, there are some inappropriate content. bah~ pity

Comment: Perhaps find a different example that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: i will post partial DOM, see if you can find anything useful? Chief? @QHarr

Comment: Sure thing. Will look.

Comment: I can try other parsing if you think it's necessary. PS i am not familiar with xpath yet. XD @QHarr

Comment: Do you need the colours separate?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "separate"? Chief! @QHarr

Comment: As in reds = ... blues = .... or simply colours = ...

Comment: at the end of my codes, there is a search criteria ```color: red``` or ```color: blue```, I am wondering if I could rewrite my six lines into one line. @QHarr

Comment: and I am asking ... are you expecting a single list as a result?

Comment: yes, yes, it would give a list of URLs, and then I use enumerate to deal with them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a attribute list to css select with ends with operator

```
[style$='color: red'],[style$='color: green'],[style$='color: blue'],[style$='color: purple'],[style$='color: orange']
```

So,

```
items = [item for item in soup.select("[style$='color: red'],[style$='color: green'],[style$='color: blue'],[style$='color: purple'],[style$='color: orange']")
```